# How can I know how long a long exposure needs to be without relying on the light meter?

Tags: low-light, long-exposure

The built in light meter for my Canon EOS Rebel T5 doesn't seem very good. It'll tell me that 30 seconds will overexpose my photo every time. I want to be able to do 1-8 minute exposures and have a workable image (not too under or over exposed)

Comment: 30 seconds *will* overexpose most photos unless it's pitch black or you have an ND filter in place...

Comment: I'm well aware that long exposures like that will normally overexpose my images. I'm talking about the times where it's still a very dark image

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are in Manual mode.
Change it to Av or Tv or simple push it to P mode.

Good luck

Comment: That's good to know, but that won't work if I go over 30 seconds using a remote timer, will it?

Comment: If you would like to take some night photography, and to use the trigger over 30sec, in M mode.
first you lock your aperture to max. 2.8, (the lower the value the faster the shutter speed will be)
After that push the shutter speed to 1/30 and after that look at the ISO value.
All this three value inport to this site [http://www.endoflow.com/exposure/](http://www.endoflow.com/exposure/) after that lock the Exposure Value, and after that change the iso value with the arrow keys on your keyboard to 400ISO, and the time value change it on your remote trigger.

Good luck